# Cambiar el valor de height CSS

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

Tengo un `iframe` que quiero que aparezca `width: 100%` y `height: 600px` en la pantalla. Luego tengo un botón que hace fullscreen el iframe y quiero que aparezca 100% x 100% y no logro hacerlo. Me coge el valor del 600px en lugar de hacerlo 100% de alto.

```
<style>
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.fullscreen-div{
  width: 100%;
}
.fullscreen-btn{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 200px;
}
.fullscreen-iframe {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>


            <div class="parent">
            <div class="fullscreen-div"></div>

            <iframe src="https://lawebquequieras.com" class="fullscreen-iframe">
            </iframe>

            <button class="fullscreen-btn " onclick="enterFullscreen()">full screen</button>
            </div>


<script>
enterFullscreen = () => {
        const el = $('.parent')[0];
        const rfs =
            el.requestFullscreen ||
            el.webkitRequestFullScreen ||
            el.mozRequestFullScreen ||
            el.msRequestFullscreen;

        rfs.call(el, Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cree la clase **fullscreen**, quite los **div** y deje el puro **botón** y el **iframe**.

Con **jQuery** le digo que si ocurre el evento click en el botón indicándolo con la clase **fullscreen-btn** entonces que le agregue la clase **fullscreen** a las propiedades del **iframe**.

```js
$('.fullscreen-btn').click(function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].className = "fullscreen";
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
.fullscreen-div{
  width: 100%;
}
.fullscreen-btn{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 200px;
}
.fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border: 0; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="https://bing.com" class="fullscreen-iframe">
</iframe>

<button class="fullscreen-btn">full screen</button>
```

Comment: Gracias pero creo que no se ha entendido. El código que me has colocado hace que nada más entrar el iframe ocupe el 100% x 100% de la pantalla. Yo lo que quiero es que cuando entres el `iframe` sea 100% x 600px de alto, y cuando haga clic en el `button` se convierta en fullscreen.

Comment: @Jok La solución es suficiente si usas dos clases una para la entrada con las condiciones que pones y cuando hagas click en el botón asignas la clase que usa la solución dada.

Comment: Pues disculpa mi ignorancia pero no se hacerlo...

Comment: @Jok ya te actualice la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias Eduardo!